# What is more readable name for boolean variables ?

Tags: php, boolean, naming-conventions

What is more readable name for Boolean "Voting is active" - in code "$newss[$i]['enabled'] == 1".

I heard that the name of the logical variables is better to call starting with "is%" 
Example code.

```
for($i=1;$i<=$newss[0];$i++) {
// pre code
    if ( $newss[$i]['enabled'] == 1 ) // boolean
        {
        // action when true
        }
    else
        {
        // action when false
        }
// post code
}
```

Variants: is_voting_active, is_active_voting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sounds better when you read it out loud? I'd say

```
if ($voting_is_active) { ... }
```

sounds better than

```
if ($is_active_voting) { ... }
```

Generally I would name boolean functions like is_active() or has_thing() and variables like foo_is_bar. But that's just a rule of thumb. Give it a name that sounds best when reading it out loud.

Comment: Just what we need! 
And which option is more correct in terms of building phrases in English?

Comment: The first one. That's why it sounds better.